# Export / Convert Flex application to HTML5

Tags: flex4.6

Please help!!! I have application generated in Flex (mxml). Now I need to export as HTML 5 but no success. Is there any software or technique to export Flex?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try FlexJs, FlexJS is a new application development framework that cross compiles MXML, more info here: [FlexJs introduction](https://www.slideshare.net/bigosmallm/flexjs-an-introduction)